# Grouping, counts and where

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, where-clause

I'm stumped and scratching my head. It must be really simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Let's say I have four tables:

```
video = id
hastag = id, tag_id, video_id
hasteam = id, team_id, video_id
hasidol = id, idol_id, video_id
```

This dataset (just as an example):

```
video = (1), (2), (3)
hastag = (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 3)
hasteam = (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 3), (3, 2, 2)
hasidol = (1, 1, 3)
```

And this query:

```
SELECT v.id ,
COUNT(vhtag.id),
COUNT(vhteam.id),
COUNT(vhidol.id)
FROM video v
LEFT JOIN hastag vhtag ON vhtag.video_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN hasteam vhteam ON vhteam.video_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN hasidol vhidol ON vhidol.video_id = v.id

WHERE
v.id <> 1
AND
(
  vhtag.tag_id IN (SELECT htt2.tag_id FROM hastag htt2 WHERE video_id = 1)
  OR
  vhteam.team_id IN (SELECT htt3.team_id FROM hasteam htt3 WHERE video_id = 1)
  OR
  vhidol.idol_id IN (SELECT htt4.idol_id FROM hasidol htt4 WHERE video_id = 1)
)
GROUP BY v.id
```

It gives me counts of "has" rows that do not correspond to the WHERE clause. For example, if the video row only has in common a single team with the video id 1, and a completely unrelated tag, it will give me "common tag count: 1, common team count: 1" when it should say "common tag count: 0 (because it's an unrelated tag), common team count: 1".

Now, as long as I restrict the query to only one "has" table, like this:

```
SELECT v.id ,
COUNT(vhtag.id)
FROM video v
LEFT JOIN hastag vhtag ON vhtag.video_id = v.id

WHERE
v.id <> 1
AND
(
  vhtag.tag_id IN (SELECT htt2.tag_id FROM hastag htt2 WHERE video_id = 1)
)
GROUP BY v.id
```

Then it does work, but the problem is when I try to put in more than one "has" table into the query. I've tried using HAVING, but it doesn't recognize the "vhtag.tag_id" column.
I'm obviously doing something wrong here, anyone can help me out?

EDIT:

This kind of works:

```
LEFT JOIN hastag vhtag ON vhtag.video_id = v.id AND vhtag.tag_id IN (SELECT htt2.tag_id FROM hastag htt2 WHERE video_id = 1)
LEFT JOIN hasteam vhteam ON vhteam.video_id = v.id AND vhteam.team_id IN (SELECT htt3.team_id FROM hasteam htt3 WHERE video_id = 1)
LEFT JOIN hasidol vhidol ON vhidol.video_id = v.id AND vhidol.idol_id IN (SELECT htt4.idol_id FROM hasidol htt4 WHERE video_id = 1)
```

And I can use that in Doctrine too (I was dumb and forgot about WITH). Is this the optimal way?

Comment: please say what is the expected result of the query or specify result on the example data..

Comment: Sorry, already edited the question a couple times after posting it. It should be more clear now.

Comment: Please provide desired resultset. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify the query, for example in this way -

```
SELECT
  v.id,
  COUNT(vhtag.id),
  COUNT(vhteam.id),
  COUNT(vhidol.id)
FROM
  video v
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM hastag WHERE video_id = 1) vhtag
  ON vhtag.video_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM hasteam WHERE video_id = 1) vhteam
  ON vhteam.video_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM hasidol WHERE video_id = 1) vhidol
  ON vhidol.video_id = v.id
WHERE
  v.id <> 1
GROUP BY
  v.id
```

Does it give correct result?

Output:

```
+------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
| id   | COUNT(vhtag.id) | COUNT(vhteam.id) | COUNT(vhidol.id) |
+------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|    2 |               0 |                0 |                0 |
|    3 |               0 |                0 |                0 |
+------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't return any rows, while the joins I posted in my edit do work. If I were to venture a guess, maybe it's because your joins are basically overlapping two conditions: video_id = 1, and video_id = v.id, which would be contradictory in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem where your joins are causing cross-joins within each team.

The simplest method is to do count distinct:

```
SELECT v.id , COUNT(distinct vhtag.id), COUNT(distinct vhteam.id),
       COUNT(distinct vhidol.id)
FROM video v LEFT JOIN
     hastag vhtag
     ON vhtag.video_id = v.id
     LEFT JOIN hasteam vhteam
     ON vhteam.video_id = v.id
     LEFT JOIN hasidol vhidol
     ON vhidol.video_id = v.id
```

The real solution is aggregate each value separately, and then join the results together.

Comment: This is not exactly what's happening. Sorry, I know I'm probably not the best at explaining, but notice there's a "1" in my queries, this is a video id passed as a parameter. It's not just joining against v.id. Check out the joins in my edit to see what I mean. Basically, it makes a relation - finding videos that share tags (that share at least one "has", that is, they have at least one instance of one of the three tag types in common) with the video whose id I'm using as a parameter (in this case, 1).